# how to implement multilingual solution in ibm websphere portal 8.0.0

Tags: websphere-portal

I have to display contents item in English and arabic languages in websphere portal 8.

Plz any body help me to know all steps required to implements my requirements.

Very Very Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your requirements?

Comment: I have two libraries with same contents items but different languages one in English and second one is in Arabic. I need to display both library on locale based.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to refer this link [Portal Language Determination](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20WebSphere%20Portal%20Express%208%20Product%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Selecting_and_changing_the_language_exp8&content=pdcontent)

You have to construct a Portal URL using the APIs provided with the correct locale. Once that is done, `portletRequest.getLocale()` will give the locale that is set. If you have the correct resource bundles inside your portlets they will be loaded automatically.